# mfc remove default toolbar

Tags: mfc, fullscreen, toolbar, statusbar

I've making simple desktop game in mfc for school project, I've managed to make my app be full screen and to remove menu bar but I can't find out how to remove default built in toolbar from my app or status bar. I tried everything that came across my mind...is there some kind of get function to call from your CWnd object to retrieve toolbar and status bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creation of `ToolBar` and `StatusBar` is inside the `CMainFrame` class. You can easily remove them if you do not need them as follows:

```
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CFrameWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
    return -1;

    // *** creation of ToolBar starts, just remark/delete the whole block if you dont't want it
    if (!m_wndToolBar.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_FLAT, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_TOP
        | CBRS_GRIPPER | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC) ||
        !m_wndToolBar.LoadToolBar(IDR_MAINFRAME))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create toolbar\n");
        return -1;      // fail to create
    }
    // *** creation of ToolBar  ends -------------------------------------------------------

    // *** creation of StatusBar starts, just remark/delete the whole block if you dont't want it
    if (!m_wndStatusBar.Create(this) ||
        !m_wndStatusBar.SetIndicators(indicators,
          sizeof(indicators)/sizeof(UINT)))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create status bar\n");
        return -1;      // fail to create
    }
    // *** creation of StatusBar ends -------------------------------------------------------

    // *** you have to remark/delete these lines too, if you removed the ToolBar above
    m_wndToolBar.EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
    EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
    DockControlBar(&m_wndToolBar);
    // *** ToolBar extra ends -------------------------------------------------------

    return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

`m_pMainWnd->SetMenu(NULL);` right before `m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);` is called in the `APPLICATION_NAME.cpp` file.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your resource file, double click on it , locate the toolbar, right click on it and choose delete :)

[image]

Comment: i've managed to do it from code. But even so I can't remove status bar.

Comment: code to remove toolbar is:
CWnd* pWnd = AfxGetMainWnd()->ChildWindowFromPoint(CPoint(5, 5), CWP_SKIPINVISIBLE);
pWnd->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);

Comment: This link http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/statusbar/article.php/c2979/Code-to-ViewHide-Status-Bar-in-SDI-and-MDI-Applications.htm contains some snippets how to remove the status bar (this is based on intercepting the relevant WM)

Comment: i've checked your link, it's no help to me, all my code is in CView class and I control displayed content by AfxGetMainWnd() function which return CWnd object, I don't have CMainFrame class access. But thanks anyway